# assigning source to html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about the code below. This is a code snippet I copied from an example. I don't understand why it works because I don't know why it can assign a URL to myscript.src. I searched for properties with element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element) and it doesn't have a property called src. Can someone offer any explanation? Thank you!

```
if (document.createElement && document.body) 
{ 
    var myscript = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); 
    myscript.src = document.location.protocol + '//myURLhere'; 
    document.body.appendChild(myscript); 
}
```

Comment: See edit, short answer: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` is not an attribute of *every* element type, which is why you don't see it in that specific MDC page. [It is, however, an attribute of `script` elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)

You can also [reference the HTML(5) spec directly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When linking to an external script, you would use the `src` attribute.

Example: `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Edit:

No, that will not work, because `<div>` does not have a src attribute. In order to load external data into a div, you would need to use AJAX. Once you load your external data from ajax, then you would use `div.innerHTML = ajaxresponse;`